# Why my code is storing data in Mysql database for almost eleven times?

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am having some problem with the mysql. Well this is my code

```
    class store_info{
            function store_info(&$bean, $event, $arguments){
                    $id = $bean->id;
                    $name = $bean->user_name . ' ' .$bean->last_name;
                    $user_hash = $bean->user_hash;
                    $query1 = "INSERT INTO sohan_password_management (id_user, name, user_password, register_date, prompt_date, deadline) VALUES('$id', '$name', '$user_hash', NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL default_prompt_date DAY, NOW() + INTERVAL default_deadline DAY)";
                    $result1 = $bean->db->query($query1, true);
                    $bean->save();
            }
    }
?>
```

whenever i run this code, data get store in database but it stores for 11 times. I mean same data get stored for more than one time in database. May I know what is wrong here? Till yesterday it was working fine. I don't know what happened to this now.

Comment: Did you call this function 11 times?

Comment: No, man. It is call after pressing save button. Till yesterday, it was going fine.

Comment: Add `echo "store_info called";` in your function

Comment: Did you press the save button 11 times?

Comment: Should i add "echo store_info called" in my function? and where? Please elaborate.

Comment: @ta.speot.is...not yaar....why should I do that and question here?

Comment: where did you call this function store_info?

Comment: it's in logic_hooks.php.....                                    <?php
        $hook_version = 1;
        $hook_array = array();
        $hook_array['after_login'] = array();
        $hook_array['after_login'][] = array(1, 'Get user info', 'custom/modules/Users/info.php', 'info', 'info');
        $hook_array['after_save'][] = array(2, 'store user info', 'custom/modules/Users/store_info.php', 'store_info', 'store_info');
?>

Comment: echo  $id = $bean->id;

Comment: yeah it is showing me current users id. No problem in that.....I think the problem in my Mysql table....I think I should look into that....thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to comment/ remove $bean->save();
I think it is a after_save logic hook and it is executing multiple times.
Also, check this post as well.
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/03_Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Examples/Preventing_Infinite_Loops_with_Logic_Hooks/

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before. It was due to a slow network connection and reloading the same page which kept submitting my input to the table. To fix this, I created a if statement to check the values of each item being submitted and if a certain number were the same values as a current column in the table, I told it not to input the data. 
After including this if statement, it worked perfectly for me.
Not sure if you can apply the same solution to your data set, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling bean save in the logic hook which is why bean is saving records multiple times.
You do not need to call the save function within a hook.